# get x and y components from ecc public key in PEM format using openssl

Tags: cryptography, openssl, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I am generating a KeyPair for [ECC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) from curve 'secp128r1' using openssl

Steps I followed :

- first I generated a private key using the command

  > openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp128r1 -noout -out private.pem
- then i viewed the corresponding public key using the command

  > openssl ec -in private.pem -text -noout

  which showed an output as :

  > read EC key
  >
  > > Private-Key: (128 bit)
  > >     priv:
  > >      00:9f:bf:2b:bd:06:86:3a:a1:bc:7c:3e:90:57:40:
  > >     f4:bc
  > >     pub: 
  > >      04:04:ce:24:34:d4:cb:f2:58:94:2f:8a:5f:06:d7:
  > >      3f:ed:5a:50:ef:fb:cc:b7:49:62:16:62:9e:aa:d5:
  > >      30:a8:a5
  > >     ASN1 OID: secp128r1

I want explicitly x and y components from the public key generated here, please can anyone suggest the correct way of doing this ?
The above public key is 264 bits long, hence cannot take(/split) it as is 
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: thanks, i'll surely put this one over there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Pub:
04:04:ce:24:34:d4:cb:f2:58:94:2f:8a:5f:06:d7:
3f:ed:5a:50:ef:fb:cc:b7:49:62:16:62:9e:aa:d5:
30:a8:a5
```

- `0x04` indicates [uncompressed form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2.2)
- From what remains:

  - X is first half `04:ce:24:34:d4:cb:f2:58:94:2f:8a:5f:06:d7:3f:ed`
  - Y is second half `5a:50:ef:fb:cc:b7:49:62:16:62:9e:aa:d5:30:a8:a5`

---

**UPD.**
Found [this website](http://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/elliptic-curve-keys/) that contains further details.

Comment: Thanks. this is pretty neat

Comment: Thanks, this is excactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to do this in nodejs, as i did when needing to share public Keys (jwk) for other people/apps to verify my signatures... here is a quick way to derive the X and Y coordinates from an secp256k1 public key:

```
import base64url from 'base64url';

function getCoordinatesFromSecp256k1PublicKey(uncompressedHexPubKey: string) {
  const publicKeyBuff = Buffer.from(uncompressedHexPubKey, 'hex');
  const pubKeyCoordsBuff = publicKeyBuff.slice(1); // First byte just signals that it is uncompressed. TRASH!
  const halfLen = Buffer.byteLength(pubKeyCoordsBuff) / 2; // should be 32;
  const x = pubKeyCoordsBuff.slice(0, halfLen);
  const y = pubKeyCoordsBuff.slice(halfLen, Buffer.byteLength(pubKeyCoordsBuff) + 1);
  return {
    x: base64url.fromBase64(x.toString('base64')),
    y: base64url.fromBase64(y.toString('base64'))
  };
}
```

This way you can return your JWK data thusly:

```
const { x, y } = getCoordinatesFromSecp256k1PublicKey(pubKey);

JSON.stringify(
    {
      use: 'sig',
      kid: 'my-keyid',
      alg: 'ECDSA',
      kty: 'EC',
      crv: 'P-256',
      x,
      y,
    },
    null,
    2
  )
```